# React-js with Firebase offline-persistance not working as Expected

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, progressive-web-apps, offline

App Works fine in Windows chrome but all this noted issues where found in Android chrome.

App works fine when user goes offline and firebase cache is also working and returning data even is offline but the problem is when user kills the app and re-open it then firebase is not returning any cached data.

STEPS :

1. install as PWA.
2. Close chrome and open as App.
3. App is working fine.
4. Now turn off the internet.
5. Still app is accessing previous cached data and returning results (Works fine).
   ---- offline ---
6. Now kill the app.
7. Now Re-open. Firestore wont return the cached results  as expected it just stucks in getDocs call.
   await getDoc() just stuck here and not executing the next line.

**NOTE:**
App passes PWA criteria in Light house.
Service worker has been added successfully and it was shown in DevTools service worker tab and we are also using workebox.

```
try {
  enableIndexedDbPersistence(db);
} catch (error) {
  window.alert(`${error.code} - Error in Persisting`)
  console.error(error)
}
```

No error has been thrown

Any suggestions, What may be the problem ?

Comment: Hi there, have you already taken a look at [1]? I know `keepSynced` is only for RTDB but you could add a listener at startup[2]. There could also be an issue with the cache size since desktops do not store the same size as mobile devices. If you have a reproducible piece of code or  application, it might be worth opening a thread with the firebase team as in [1]. 

[1] https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/39

[2] https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/

Comment: @AntonioRamirez thanks for your reply,  we are using react js as our front end and it's seems authentication is the issue in mobile web,  since firebase need internet to check whether user is valid.